# How do i copy a python file from my windows to Linux subsystem after connect ssh to my server?

Tags: python, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

At first, I can use this to access my files.

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/
```

but after I connected ssh to my server. I'm no longer get to access files in my windows.

How do I can run my python file after being connected to a server from my windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your SSH server is located outside of your computer, you need to copy the file to the server. You can do it with scp [How to use SCP](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/scp)